# How to run for loop with float-number in range

Tags: python-2.7, list, for-loop

I tried running my long code but the idea in these short lines.

My issue needs two conditions. The first one which `i` is within range. The second one uses all values in the list

```
m = [181.452, 147.0213, 480.33, 1000.05]
for i in m:
    if i in range(0 , 200):
        print ('Red')
    if i in range(201 , 500):
        print ('white')
    if i in range(501 , 1000):
        print ('green')
    if i in range(1000 , 1500):
        print ('blue')
```

you can see when values in list `int`:

```
m = [181, 147.0213, 480.33, 1000.05]
for i in m:
    if i in range(0 , 200):
        print ('Red')
    if i in range(201 , 500):
        print ('white')
    if i in range(501 , 1000):
        print ('green')
    if i in range(1000 , 1500):
        print ('blue')
```

output to second code: `Red`

Comment: `for i in range`, not `if`

Comment: What prevents you from running the code? You have not stated what problem you are having or asked a question.

Comment: I edited  my question

Comment: It is fine now, I converted `float` to `int`:  `if int(i) in range(0 , 200) :`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `range()` which returns an iterator of `int` values, so your code is not working. It means if you have written

```
if i in range(0,5)
```

then it will translate to:

```
if i in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

So your float values didn't got captured here. Also it's not a good practice to use iterator for comparison, when you have comparison operators.
Use below code:

```
m = [181.452, 147.0213, 480.33, 1000.05]

for i in m:
    if 0 <= i <= 200:     # this is pythonic way to write "if i >= 0 and i <= 200"
        print('Red')
    elif 200 < i <= 500:
        print ('white')
    elif 500 < i <= 1000:
        print ('green')
    elif 1000 < i <= 1500:
        print ('blue')
```

Output:

```
Red
Red
white
blue
```